# Why are there duplicate game entries in my Steam library?

Tags: steam, civilization-4, steam-play

I purchased [Sid Meier's Civilization IV: The Complete Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/4323/), a package that includes four items. Three of the included items are displayed twice in my games library, with the message *[game] is not available on your current platform*.

Why do these duplicate entries exist, and can I hide or remove them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seeing as that game is a SteamPlay game, the duplicates are Mac versions of the game.

The easiest way to hide any game is to categorise your games and only show those you want to see, or just hide those that are not installed. You can do so by clicking `All Games` and clicking the category you want to see.

Alternatively, at least in library mode, if you give them a certain category they will be put in a different section which you can hide by clicking.

Comment: I just confirmed that when you buy the game you get both Mac and Windows versions in your list. It's nothing abnormal. My suggestions obviously still stand.

Answer (score 8):

I submitted a question to Steam Support a while back on this ... got the following response ...

> Hello Bryan,
>
> Thank you for contacting Steam
>   Support.
>
> Currently, all copies of Civilization
>   IV games have double listings (One for
>   PC and one for Mac).
>
> We are aware of this issue and working
>   to correct it in the near future.
>
> Our apologies for the inconvenience.
>
> If you have any further questions,
>   please let us know.

... looks like Arda Xi is correct!